# How to enable chat in advance for a question?

Tags: support, comments, chat

I have already asked some questions where the comment section turned into a discussion, however the option of moving it to the chat prompted only after a major number of comments accumulated. Is there a way to previously enable chat, when a discussion is already forming, instead of having to wait for the comment section to get too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as a user got 50 rep, yes. First, you go to the chat section:

[image]

There, on the lower right end of the site, you can open a new chat room (or get the link to an existing one:

[image]

You can link to any existing chatroom.